# Python: Modifying external variables from within a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a thread that runs within a class.

But I want to modify a variable (say, self.variable) within that class from the thread.

Since the thread creates a copy of self.variable, but I need to update it on the fly within the thread, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you'd provide code  (better simplified down to parts in question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question. I have created a code snippet, after guessing what you really want to do.

> **Q**. I have a thread that runs within a class. But I want to modify a
>   variable (say, self.variable) within that class from the thread.

The code snippet below runs a thread in the class named as `myThreadClass()`. This class has a variable named as `self.myVariable` in its `__init__()`. In the `run()` the value of `self.myVariable` is incremented/modified for the demo purpose. Later the value of `self.myVariable` is printed from the `myThreadClass()` itself as well as it is later printed from the `main()` too.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class myThreadClass(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myVariable = 0

        print ('Value of myVariable is: %d')%self.myVariable#Initial value
        self.daemon = False
        print 'Starting Child thread.\n'
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        k = 1
        for i in range(0,5):
            self.myVariable = self.myVariable+k #Increment the value and assign
            print ('Value of self.myVariable now is: %d')%self.myVariable#Print current value
            k += 1

        print 'The final value of self.myVariable is: %d'%self.myVariable
        print 'Child thread finished its job'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = myThreadClass()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'This is the main thread. The value of self.myVariable is: %d'%obj.myVariable
```

The console output will be:

```
Value of myVariable is: 0
Starting Child thread.

Value of myVariable now is: 1
Value of myVariable now is: 3
Value of myVariable now is: 6
Value of myVariable now is: 10
Value of myVariable now is: 15
The final value of self.myVariable is: 15
Child thread finshed its job
This is the main thread. The value of myVariable is: 15
```

Is this what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you tho create your thread class like this

```
class ThClass( threading.Thread ):

   # parent is a object of Main, below
    def __init__( self,parent):
       super(ThClass,self).__init__()
       parent.yourvar=x
    ......do stuff


class Main():

   def __init__(self):
     super(Main,self).__init__()
     self.myth=ThClass(self)
     self.myth.start()
     ......do stuff
```